# How to pass string from first html page to second html page in chromium framework (CEF)?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I have two html page and I need to pass string value of first html page to second html page. I abed to get string value from first html page and now i want to pass to second html page.

I have tried this but does not work

const int64 frame_id =frame->GetIdentifier();  // getting frame id of second html page in OnContextCreated() method

```
      CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> contextRef1;
      string st = value;     //value from first html page
 CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame = contextRef1->GetFrame(frame_id );
CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context = frame->GetV8Context();
CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> contextRef2 = context->GetCurrentContext();
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object1 = contextRef2->GetGlobal();
str = CefV8Value::CreateString(value);
 object1->SetValue("myval", str, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
```